# Tag excerpt disappears when clicking "Reject and Edit"

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-excerpt

As the title says the content (text) of the tag excerpt disappear when reviewing an edit suggestion and trying to click "Reject and Edit".

> [image]

This doesn't seem to happen for tag wiki edit suggestions according to [Matt♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308860/tag-excerpt-disappears-when-clicking-reject-and-edit#comment263429_308860).

Browser: Firefox 41.0.2

Comment: Regarding *this probably also happens with tag wiki edit*; it doesn't; I just checked :).