# Why was this tag wiki edit unanimously approved but the excerpt edit was unanimously rejected?

Tags: discussion, meta, rejected-edits, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

I recently created a tag wiki entry for [instant-self-answer](/questions/tagged/instant-self-answer). The wiki entry proper was accepted, but the excerpt was rejected, both unanimously, both by the same reviewers, and I'm not sure if it was because I wrote a genuinely inferior excerpt or if the feature is buggy. I understand that the tags element here has recently been revised, and found [this recent post by another user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308860/tag-excerpt-disappears-when-clicking-reject-and-edit) reporting a problem. I want to be sure, though, both for my own knowledge and potentially to call attention to a problem with (M)SO. If it makes any difference, I wrote and submitted both wiki and excerpt at the same time.

I also thought that, absent a specific excerpt, the first few lines of the wiki would appear by default in tag mouseovers and in excerpt box. Not so! (It may be on my side; I'm using Firefox 28.)

The [review log for the wiki entry is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7106), and [the review log for the excerpt is here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7107)

For those interested, I based the excerpt loosely off the one for [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) and from the [tags redesign post in the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) (but that doesn't mean it was good).

Comment: Tangental: Maybe it's just me, but I really don't see the point of the instant-self-answer tag. What discussions/bugs/support requests are served by the tag, that the self-answer tag isn't already quite capable of?

Comment: @theB I imagine there are situations where questions arise to do with posting answers-at-once to your own questions-- the validity of posting personal research; finding and solving a curious problem on one's own; new-user stuff-- that relate substantially to the *immediacy* of self-answered questions ("Should I wait for other users to offer their solutions, or charge ahead with my own?" for instance, maybe), rather than merely posting an answer to a question you happen to have written.
I'm not sure if twelve people thinking it's worth while is enough to make it so, though. :v

Comment: So, it's for questions whether the instant self-answering should be removed?

Comment: I suspect, but am not sure, that they really meant more "this excerpt is just the tag name again", even though there's a dedicated rejection reason for that. That's how it looks to me. However, keep in mind that writing a tag wiki (excerpt) from scratch *and getting it approved* is surprisingly difficult.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think it's more about situations regarding questions posted at the same time as their answers in general, like when it's appropriate, whether people should bother at all, and cases where posts should be removed, or when they have been removed and why.

The tag doesn't have a hugely-broad scope, but it isn't totally useless, either.

Comment: I agree with @theB, The fact that someone `instant-self-answer`s their post does not mean they have not put research into it. The option to self answer is there for a reason. And by tagging a post as `instant-self-answer` it will already be put in a negative daylight, if I read the wiki correctly.

Comment: @Bas I agree, a couple of my own posts are something that I already know but constantly get asked about, so I make them into a Q&A. Instant answers never mean that the question or answer is bad.

Comment: @Augusta It may be just the whims of reviewers but I added one that was accepted. I did try to focus more on disambiguation in usage, which might also have helped.